# Vue & Vuex: Using computed property for v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuetify switch that uses a v-model for `true` and `false` . I use a computed property for `couponProgramToggle` that returns the state from the store.
When I set to `return true` just to test it out, it works perfectly but when I set it to `return this.$store.getters.isCouponProgramActive;`, I am getting an infinite loop that is cause the Max Stack error in the JS console.

```
   <v-switch v-model="couponProgramToggle"></v-switch>
```

///

```
    computed: {
        couponProgramToggle: {
            console.log(this.$store.getters.isCouponProgramActive;) <--- logs to "true"
            get () {
              return this.$store.getters.isCouponProgramActive;
            },
            set (value) {
              this.$store.commit('toggleCouponProgram', value)
            }
          },
    },
```

edit:

```
  state: {
    isCouponProgramActive: null
  },

  getters: {
    isCouponProgramActive(state) {
        return state.isCouponProgramActive
    }
  },
```

Comment: The `console.log` is in the wrong place, it's a syntax error. Can you provide the code for the `isCouponProgramActive` getter?

Comment: I reproduced the example with the code you provided - it works.
https://codepen.io/curveball/pen/KKKYxdL

Comment: @curveball thanks, strange!  It must be something else then.  Thanks for taking the time to make a codepen :)